# Thunderbird, LatexIt! extension - convert failed with error code 1

Tags: latexit

Since recently deleted from StackOverflow for being off topic, I would like to repost the following question (originally asked by User [Фадиме Бекмамбетова](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7815973/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0)):

When using the LatexIt! extension for thunderbird on Ubuntu I get the error:

```
LatexIt! run report...
*** Found expression $a$
convert failed with error code 1. Aborting.
Possible explanations include:
- you're running Windows, and you didn't install Ghostscript
- you're running OSX, and you didn't launch Thunderbird from a Terminal
Please see http://github.com/protz/LatexIt/wiki
```

When running from inside a terminal, I get

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
This is dvips(k) 5.995 Copyright 2015 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2018.10.12:1055' -> /tmp/tblatex-1.ps
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/base/tex.pro>
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/base/texps.pro>.
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb>[1] 
convert: not authorized `/tmp/tblatex-1.ps' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/412.
convert: no images defined `/tmp/tblatex-1.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3210.
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 3):

In `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` you have to change (needs root) the line

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PS" />
```

to

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="read | write" pattern="PS" />
```

Related: [Wand Policy Error: error/constitute.c/ReadImage/412](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52699608/wand-policy-error-error-constitute-c-readimage-412)

Comment: any alternative to this? I appear not to have the permissions to modifiy the .xml however I am able to use the convert command on a console

Comment: That worked great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note that I'm pushing an update to the addon right now that does not rely on convert but instead uses dvipng directly.